# Significance of parashah of the week a child is born

Tags: names

Did Chazal ever teach about any significance attached to the parashah of the week a child is born in terms of picking the child's name or otherwise raising them?

Comment: Chazal, definitely not. Some of the modern Chasidic Rabbis might have mentioned it.

Comment: On a personal level, I've made efforts to draw inspiration for myself from my parsha.